# How to Correctly Type Next.js getServerSideProps as a Function Declaration

Tags: typescript, next.js

I'm working with typing `getServerSideProps` ([guide docs](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching/get-server-side-props), [API reference docs](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/data-fetching/get-server-side-props)) but all of the documentation that I can find relates to declaring it as a function expression. I'm looking to code it as a function declaration but can't find any documentation on it and am having trouble getting it to work.

As a function expression (this works):

```
import { GetServerSideProps } from 'next';

export type Data = {
  example: string,
};

export const getServerSideProps: GetServerSideProps<data: Data> = async (context) => {
    const data: Data = { example: '' };
    ...
    return {
        props: data
    };
}
```

This is where I'm at with it as a function declaration:

```
import { GetServerSideProps, GetServerSidePropsContext } from 'next';

export type Data = {
    example: string,
};

export async function getServerSideProps(context: GetServerSidePropsContext): Promise<GetServerSideProps<data: Data>> {
    const data: Data = { example: '' };
    ...
    return {
        props: data
    };
}
```

TypeScript is happy with this as far as the declaration itself goes, but I get an error on the  component declaration `TS2339: Property 'example' does not exist on type 'never'.`

```
export default function ExampleComponent(data: InferGetServerSidePropsType<typeof getServerSideProps>) {
    return (
        <>
            <p>{data.example}</p>
        </>
    );
}
```

What am I missing? How can I properly use a function declaration for `getServerSideProps` and get the typing right?

Thanks.

Comment: Maybe you should correct the numerous mismatches in names here... I see `PartData`/`partData` and `Data`/`data`... which one is it? I fixed them myself here: https://tsplay.dev/wXzxkm. Is this what your example is supposed to be?

Comment: Not sure that one counts as "numerous". I updated that. Just from changing the code to an example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok pretty sure I found the correct answer to this now, having discovered the `GetServerSidePropsResult` type from `next`.

```
import { GetServerSidePropsContext, GetServerSidePropsResult } from 'next';

export async function getServerSideProps(context: GetServerSidePropsContext): Promise<GetServerSidePropsResult<Data>> {
    const data: Data = { example: '' };
    ...
    return {
        props: data
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**This works but see my other answer which makes better use of the types provided by Next.js.**

Looks like I found an answer to this myself but if this can be done better then I'd appreciate hearing about it.

```
import { GetServerSidePropsContext } from 'next';

export async function getServerSideProps(context: GetServerSidePropsContext): Promise<{props: Data}> {
    const data: Data = { example: '' };
    ...
    return {
        props: data
    }
}
```