# How to Correctly Type Next.js getStaticPaths as a Function Declaration

Tags: typescript, next.js

I'm working with typing `getStaticPaths` ([guide docs](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching/get-static-paths), [API reference docs](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/data-fetching/get-static-paths)) but all of the documentation that I can find relates to declaring it as a function expression. I'm looking to code it as a function declaration but can't find any documentation on it and am having trouble getting it to work.

As a function expression (this works):

```
import { GetStaticPaths } from 'next';

export const getStaticPaths: GetStaticPaths = async () => {
  return {
    paths: [{ params: { id: 'example' } }],
    fallback: false,
  }
}
```

How can I properly use a function declaration for `getStaticPaths` and get the typing right?

Comment: Why are you converting all your callbacks to function declarations?

Comment: It's not a callback, it's a function expression. I'm doing it to have a consistent approach to the coding rather than a mix of function expressions and function declarations.

Comment: Well I call it a callback since Next.js is going to call it later, but the consistency you should maintain here is that your special Next.js functions are function expressions and everything else is a function declaration. It's just annoying when the style you want makes things super complicated.

Comment: I'm not seeing how it makes it complicated, let alone "super complicated", nor how that brings any consistency. I actually have the answer for this but can't post it yet (30 mins between posts), and am asking the question in order to provide the info for others. See related question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75009342/how-to-correctly-type-getserversideprops-as-a-function-declaration It's just a case of using `getStaticPaths(): Promise<GetStaticPathsResult>`.

Comment: @vera. On the topic of callbacks, well that's not a callback even in a loose sense. Callbacks are function references that are passed to be called later. Next is going to "call" this, true, but it's no "callback" and no specific function reference involved. Next is going to call everything here, so it's not even special.

Comment: One final point here, and sorry for the multiple comments, but Next.js documentation does actually use function declarations for the documentation of these. See https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/data-fetching/get-static-paths but simply doesn't cover it in the TypeScript section, so I'm really not seeing any validity to saying that this is "annoying" by which I'm presuming you mean it makes coding difficult for others working on the same codebase and is non-standard or something like that. I'm not seeing that it is. It simply seems to be a lack of documentation on using TS with Next.js.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is achieved by making use of the `GetStaticPathsResult` type from `next`.

```
import {GetStaticPathsResult} from 'next';

export async function getStaticPaths(): Promise<GetStaticPathsResult> {
  return {
    paths: [{ params: { id: 'example' } }],
    fallback: false,
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I did see it but it's not correct. It returns props rather than paths and doesn't have the correct data format for that. Looks like you have a mix of what's needed for GetStaticPaths vs. GetStaticProps.

Comment: Agreed but I wanted to post a correct answer. I actually already had it and asked the question just to make the info available for others (but had to wait 30 mins between posts which is when you answered), so I want to make sure there's a fully correct answer that can be accepted. See related question at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75009342/how-to-correctly-type-getserversideprops-as-a-function-declaration when I actually didn't have the answer! Thanks.

Comment: Well yes it is the point, since I don't want to accept an answer that isn't accurate and usable, particularly since that was the whole point of spending the time posting this in the first place.

Comment: Fair enough. Since you opened the discussion with "I think you didn't see my answer" I was following through based on that.